# How does Scrapy (Open Source Web Scraping Framework) works?

Tags: parsing, dom, web-scraping, scrapy, data-extraction

Quoting from Scrapy Official Documentation :

> Scrapy comes with its own mechanism for extracting data. They’re called selectors because they “select” certain parts of the HTML document specified either by XPath or CSS expressions. [Source](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

After reading this, I'm still not sure whether Scrapy works by directly selecting parts of the HTML document by using XPath/CSS expressions or selecting nodes from DOM Tree which is rendered by the browser?

Still confused whether DOM Parsing and HTML Parsing is the same or not...

Answer (score 1):

> After reading this, I'm still not sure whether Scrapy works by directly selecting parts of the HTML document by using XPath/CSS expressions or selecting nodes from DOM Tree which is rendered by the browser?

For sure the former, as there is definitely no browser involved. Even the "CSS" part is just syntatic sugar for the XPath part -- which one can see by printing out an "in progress" `Selector`:

```
>>> print(Selector(text="<html><div class='foo'></div></html>").css(".foo"))
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' foo ')]" data='<div class="foo"></div>'>]
```

> Still confused whether DOM Parsing and HTML Parsing is the same or not...

Strictly speaking, I believe they are different. For example, lxml is able to parse HTML, but it does so in its own way, and materializes an object tree that is `xml.etree` compatible, and not that of the [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1590626202). There is a [minimal DOM library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#minidom-and-the-dom-standard) that [html5lib can target](https://html5lib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/movingparts.html#tree-builders), which is about the closest you'll get to "what a browser would build"